# How to mask numpy array by date?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a function:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

time = pd.date_range("2021-09-09 04:22:00", "2021-09-10 19:59:00", freq="1min")
print(time.shape)
from IPython.display import display
time = pd.Series(time, time)

out = np.full(time.shape, False)

# loop through our times
for i in range(time.shape[0]):
    # only enter trades between 4am and 6am
    if (time[i].hour >= 4) & (time[i].hour <= 6):
        out[i] = True
    print(out[i])
    print(time[i])
```

Which gives me:

```
(2378,)
True
2021-09-09 04:22:00
True
2021-09-09 04:23:00
True
2021-09-09 04:24:00
True
2021-09-09 04:25:00
True
2021-09-09 04:26:00
True
2021-09-09 04:27:00
True
2021-09-09 04:28:00
True
2021-09-09 04:29:00
True
2021-09-09 04:30:00
True
2021-09-09 04:31:00
True
2021-09-09 04:32:00
True
2021-09-09 04:33:00
...
False
2021-09-10 19:58:00
False
2021-09-10 19:59:00
```

How can I mask it so that only one date is chosen? Something like:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

time = pd.date_range("2021-09-09 04:22:00", "2021-09-10 19:59:00", freq="1min")
time = pd.Series(time, time)

start_date = '2021-09-09'

out = np.full(time.shape, False)

# loop through our closes
for i in range(time.shape[0]):
    # only enter trades between 4am and 6am
    if time[i] == start_date:
        if (time[i].hour >= 4) & (time[i].hour <= 6):
            out[i] = True
    print(out[i])
    print(time[i])
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if I get the problem, but in this case probably is better to work with `pandas` instead of `numpy`:

```
#in
time = pd.date_range("2021-09-09 04:22:00", "2021-09-10 19:59:00", freq="1min")

df = pd.DataFrame(index=time, columns=["mask"])
df.iloc[df.index.indexer_between_time("04:00","18:00"), 0] = True
df["mask"].replace(np.nan, False, inplace=True)

#out
df
```

[image]

Comment: It has to be Numpy inside a loop (as in the OP) sadly :( thanks for your response though!